# Cloudcode - Combine two OR queries using AND

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using the javascript API/Cloudcode, is there a way to take two OR queries and combine them using AND?

```
var orQuery1 = Parse.Query.or(q1, q2);
var orQuery2 = Parse.Query.or(q3, q4);

var orQuery1AndorQuery2 = ??
```

In the above example, I would the final query to return the results of (q1 || q2) && (q3 || q4)

Comment: I don't know parse.com, but I'll bet it's something like `Parse.Query.and(orQuery1, orQuery2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to combine to Or queries I had to use the method "matchesKeyInQuery()".

If I have 4 queries q1, q2, q3, q4 and I want my final query to be the result of (q1 || q2) && (q3 || q4).

You first create 2 Or queries:

```
var q1OrQ2 = Parse.Query.or(q1, q2);
var q3OrQ4 = Parse.Query.or(q3, q4);
```

Then you add q3OrQ4 onto the first query using matchesKeyInQuery:

```
var finalQuery = q1OrQ2.matchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "objectId", q3OrQ4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.. not sure it will work, but worth a shot:

```
var query3 = new Parse.Query("TargetClassName");
query3.whereMatchesQuery("objectId", orQuery1);
query3.whereMatchesQuery("objectId", orQuery2);

query3.find().then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

If this doesn't work, you'll need to pull the 2 queries and combine/filter them on the client-side.